# How can I assign a key to an array of values to pass to an API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Im using Angular with pure JS. I have an array like this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 5, 32];
```

But I need to POST this to an API in JSON. I'm trying to achieve this:

```
{'reportIDs': [1, 2, 5, 32]}
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wherever it is that you need this value, you can create that object almost exactly as in your question:

```
var obj = {'reportIDs': arr};
```

You don't need the `'`, but they don't do any harm.

But if you really need to send **JSON**, your example isn't JSON. In JSON, property names must be in *double* quotes. The simplest way to create valid JSON is to use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({reportIDs:arr});
```

If you're sending that somewhere, you'd use that value as the `data` in a `$http` call.

You might want to use [`angular.toJson`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson) instead of using `JSON.stringify` directly, as it skips some internal Angular prooperties.

Comment: Thanks the formatting at the top was exactly what I was looking for. Question though regarding your second snippet: I've never needed to explicitly define the data I'm POSTing as JSON. I thought that Angular did that behind the scenes. I was able to POST essentially using the syntax in Thanasis's answer below. What's the value of applying JSON.stringify?

Comment: JSON.stringify converts the json code from an Object to a String. For example `var a = JSON.stringify({str : "123"})` is the same as `var a = "{\"str\":\"123\"}"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to sent an Ajax request to the server

If you want to keep the json code, insert it as a string

```
$http.post("the_url_to_sent_data",
   {'json' : JSON.stringify({'reportIDs': arr})}
).then(function (response) {
    // Hey, i got a responce
    return response;
});
```

Then get the json parameter's value and parse it.

Or just send the data and let the library parse them

```
$http.post("the_url_to_sent_data",
   {'reportIDs': arr}
).then(function (response) {
    // Hey, i got a responce
    return response;
});
```

Comment: How does that send JSON? The [default param serializer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer) does standard URI-encoding, not JSON.

Comment: Include the json inside a parameter as a text. Then parse it on server side. I thought the problem was the Ajax.

Comment: I thought your answer was correct. My final code looked like: $scope.getOptions = function() {
  var data = {reportIDs: $scope.reportIDs};
  $scope.loading = true;
  $http.post('/api/reports/options', data)
  .then (function successCallback(response) {
   $scope.loading = false;
   $scope.optionsData = response.data.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
   $scope.loading = false;
  });
 };